# Rpc methods not decorated

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, parachain, rpc, rococo

**Goal**
I'm trying to decorate the rpc methods to be able to interact with api.tx. If anyone has faced this issue, what has helped you out?

**Issue**
I'm not able to access tx method inside of api, which I believe is caused by the error message.

*Error*
API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: chainSpec_v1_chainName, chainSpec_v1_genesisHash, chainSpec_v1_properties
WARN  2024-03-20 16:57:24        API/INIT: rococo/1006002: Not decorating runtime apis without matching versions: ParachainHost/10 (1/2/3/4/5 known)
WARN  2024-03-20 16:57:24        API/INIT: rococo/1006002: Not decorating unknown runtime apis: 0xfbc577b9d747efd6/1

Current Code Environment:
const provider = new WsProvider('ws://192.168.1.212:9944');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });

Comment: Do you mean you want augmented type support in your IDE, or are there no keys under `api.tx` when you run `Object.keys(api.tx)`. Do you get an empty array?

Comment: I receive this array as a response to Object.keys(api.tx) : ["system", "babe", "timestamp", "indices", "balances",..."rootTesting", "sudo"]. When I try to access an object from the array for transaction purposes, I get this error message: api.tx.balances is 'undefined'. @TarikGul